# getting Document Mode with Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

i´d like to get the Documend Mode of the internet explorer.
At the moment i´d tried something like this:

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7.0");
```

this does work, when the IE starts and it´s in document mode 7.0

but if i change it in the Browser to 8.0 for example, the method

```
navigator.userAgent;
```

still gets the rusult, beeing shown in document mode 7.0. so even if i say

```
navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 8.0");
```

after switching from document mode 7.0 to 8.0 the index of this will be -1.

It seems as i got no way to change the navigator.userAgent to anything else then 7.0, becuase it does allways startup with this value. Even so if i add a meta tag like this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

to the .html, it does start up with document mode 7.0, and after switching the document mode once the navigator.userAgent changed to document mode 8.0, but it keeps this mode.

So now my Question, is there any way to get the internet explorer´s document mode, even if he does change it while he´s on the side?

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me with IE10 on Windows 7. I changed the browser and document mode of this page to IE7 and ran this command in browser console (F12): `navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 7.0")`, it returned 25. Then I changed it to IE8 and checked with `MSIE 8.0` and it returned 25 again.

Comment: for me it doesnt change the userAgent information, and i really don´t know why

Comment: i know wheres my mistake now, i am getting the browsermode, but not the Dokumentmode...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `browser mode` in addition to `document mode`. Navigator object gives information about current browser. You can find more information [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/19/testing-sites-with-browser-mode-vs-doc-mode.aspx).

Comment: even so i found this fine  piece of code, `document.documentMode` and `j.browser.version.slice(0,j.browser.version.indexOf("."));` know i am able to compare both options in IE.

link to the source of this: http://my.opera.com/Schalandra/blog/2012/02/29/how-to-detect-different-browser-mode-and-document-mode-in-ie